# JNI Tutorial, cant'load library

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

i am trying to do this tutorial it's for JNI

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/beginning-jni-linux.html

i already did everything in there, but i am having this trouble

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /home/usr/NetBeansProjects/JNIDemoCdl/dist/libJNIDemoCdl.so
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1846)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1061)
at jnidemojava.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:13)
```

Java Result: 1

i am kind of stuck with JNI for a time now, and i could use some help, thanks

Comment: May sound stupid but did you check that the library is at the exact path the error messages prints out?

Comment: Yes, that's the awful thing about this, it is in fact there, i double check

Comment: @user3182920 64 bit vs 32 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have read/write permissions recursively over the directory structure and the lib file itself.

Try

```
sudo chmod ug+rwX -R /home/usr/NetBeansProjects/
```

That will add read/write permissions  to the files and dirs, and execute permissions on directories and files that already have the execute flag for a user.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I never use mac but using windows i have faced same problem when i start working with jni.
 With your problem it could be many things or one
the created dll flag is not correct, make sure you have used correct command to create dll.
i use the following command

```
gcc -Wall -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_ -Wl,--kill-at -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\win32" -shared -o Sample1.dll Sample1.cpp
```

for this i used mingw compiler.

- in windows dll file on mac this will so.
  i used the command
  `System.loadlibrary("youLibraryNameWithoutExtensionAndPath")`
  before this go to your project build path and expand jre and select native library then click brows and select folder where you put dll/so file and ok.
  now try to run your code. this will solve issue.

but if the dll/so file have dependent lib then you have to put all dll file in system32 folder (in windows)